# Value in TWITTER Environment Variables

Tags: python, twitter, nlp, nltk

I have followed tutorial from this site : http://www.nltk.org/howto/twitter.html

Right now my problem is I don't know what are the values in Environment Variables need to be input. I am using Windows 7.

> On a Unix-like system (including MacOS), you will set the variable something like this:
>
> export TWITTER="/path/to/your/twitter-files"
>
> Rather than having to give this command each time you start a new session, it's advisable to add it to your shell's configuration file, e.g. to .bashrc.
>
> On a Windows machine, right click on “My Computer” then select Properties > Advanced >        Environment Variables > User Variables > New...

I try input the value with path to 'twitter-file'

[image]

When I run the code in python-notebook:

```
from nltk.twitter import Twitter
tw = Twitter()
tw.tweets(keywords='love, hate', limit=10) #sample from the public stream
```

I got this error :

```
ValueError: Supply a value to the 'subdir' parameter or set the TWITTER environment variable.
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue (Under Windows 10.) A little background, to make sure we're on the same page- I'm using Anaconda 2 and running the exact same tutorial you reference in a Jupyter notebook. I set the same user environment variable you did:
[environment variable screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFK5A.png)

At this point I kept coming up with the same ValueError when calling Twitter(). I ran: `% env` to see exactly what was in my working environment and found that the TWITTER environment variable I had set was missing. I reasoned that Jupyter was pulling the environment variables when the program started.

The Fix- I closed Jupyter and Anaconda 2 (and all related windows.) On restarting Jupyter and again running: `% env` The TWITTER environment variable was now listed and the examples from the tutorial are returning results:

```
tw = Twitter()
tw.tweets(keywords='love, hate', limit=10) #sample from the public stream
```

[Tutorial Results screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnvjl.png)

I apologize for the verbose reply- I hope this helps.